# Prove that two metric are equivalent

Tags: general-topology

> Let $O$ be the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the map $d_1: \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$
> $$
>  d_1(P,Q)= \cases{
>     0 & P = Q\cr
>     d(P,O) + d(Q,O) & P ≠ Q
> }
> $$
> Where $d$ is the euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that this two are equivalent

After checking that $d_1$ is a metric, thanks to triangular inequality $\forall P,Q \in \mathbb{R}^2 $
$$d(P,Q) \leq d(P,O) + d(Q,O) = d_1(P,Q)$$
So I think that each open ball in $d_1$-metric contains an euclidean ball. I don't really
know how to proceed further. Thank you!

Comment: Consider $P=(1,0)$ and $Q=(0,1)$. Then, $d(P,Q)=\sqrt{2}\neq 2 = d(P,O)+d(Q,O)=d_1(P,Q)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to prove is not true. Let $P \neq O$. Then any $d_1$-ball around $P$ of radius less than $d(P,O)$ only contains the point $P$. Thus $\{P\}$ is open w.r.t. $d_1$ but not w.r.t. $d$.